# How to have the Spring Security filter be run after a @Before integration test data insertion

Tags: java, spring, security, integration

My Spring Security queries a database table for user credentials. On an integration testing environment, I insert the user in the database table in a @Before annotated method.

But the trouble is that the Spring Security filter seems to be fired even before that method.

And so, the user credentials are not found and the test fails.

Any clue on where to put the user credential insert point ?

Kind Regards,

Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can at least offer some JUnit advice: if you have some setup that needs to occur before anything else, use the `@BeforeClass` annotation on a static method.